# Books recommendation on syntax, semantics and pragmatics interaction

Tags: syntax, semantics

Can anyone here suggest any texts that deals especially with the interaction between Semantics, Pragmatics and Syntax?

I would like to  understand how these various levels, especially syntax-semantics, are linked.

Answer (score 1):

A classic for the syntax-semantics interface is Heim & Kratzer (1998), and shorter versions of their kind of presentation can be found in many introductory semantics textbooks, such as Kearns (2011) ch. 4. Though I much prefer Coppock & Champollion (2020), because it is more precise about the formalism used while at the same time being written accessibly enough even for beginners i.m.o. These books aim at providing rules that link syntax trees with semantic composition, e.g. complementation roughly corresponds to function application.
Coppock & Champollion also have sections on presupposition, anaphora and discourse and context dependence, which are at the borderline between semantics and pragmatics. That borderlineness is what the "interaction" between semantics and pragmatics pretty much comes down to.

If you're into close interaction between syntax and semantics, you might like categorial grammar. You could start with the corresponding chapter in Müller (2020) and check out more advanced literature from there.

---

Coppock, Elizabeth & Champollion, Lucas (2020). *[Invitation to formal semantics](http://eecoppock.info/bootcamp/semantics-boot-camp.pdf)*. Manuscript.

Heim, Irene & Kratzer, Angelika (1998). *Semantics in generative grammar*. Blackwell Oxford.

Kearns, Kate (2011). *Semantics*. Palgrave Macmillan, 2nd edition.

Müller, Stefan (2020). *[Grammatical theory: From transformational grammar to constraint-based approaches](https://langsci-press.org/catalog/book/287)*. Language Science Press, 4th edition.

Comment: McCawley has [a book on syntax](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html) and one on [semantics, pragmatics, and logic](https://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/E/bo3618384.html). They work nicely together. Though calling the relation an "interface" is just metaphor; it's not that regular or predictable.